# Creating Google Music Album deck custom listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am bootstrapping an app and for my case the below layout from Google music album deck really makes a lot of sense in my tablet app. I love the widget's experience.

[image: the album deck from the Google music app]

Is there an Android view library available out there in the opensource world (preferred, because I can achieve it faster) or a tutorial which puts me in the right direction towards implementing my own?

Any thoughts on how I can develop one if required?

Comment: [coverflow?](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rendered in [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) and is called the carousel-view

You can download a working copy of the sample+source here: http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=2&q=